# Using RegExr to skip first position match Javascript

Tags: regex

try to replace string `IPProtocol` become `I_p_protocol`

```
str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`)
```

produce `_i_p_protocol`

Comment: Try this: `(?!^)[A-Z]`

Comment: Solved. Need to learn more regex. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead to make sure not string from start of string:
`(?!^)[A-Z]`

```js
const str = "IPProtocol";

const new_str = str.replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);

console.log(new_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```js
var str = 'IPProtocol';
var r = str.replace(/\B[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);

console.log(r)
//=> "I_p_protocol"
```

Here we are using `\B[A-Z]` which makes an uppercase letter match between word character but not at first place of a word.

Comment: I have a hard time to understand what is the word boundary. Could you explain a little more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A word boundary or `\b` is position between a word character i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and a non-word character. `\B` is inverse of of `\b` hence it matches position between 2 word characters only.

Comment: A second letter "P" is not a word if I am understand correctly, why it doesn't count

Comment: We are talking about word character here. Both P appear after another letter hence word boundary is not matched before rhwm

Comment: Please [check this help article on `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)